# Can't get Jetty to scan for annotated classes in fat Jar

Tags: java-8, embedded-jetty, jetty-9

I have an application with an embedded jetty server which I'm starting up like this (placed in main() and launched with eclipse)

```
Server server = new Server(port);
WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
context.setResourceBase("web/");
context.setDescriptor("web/WEB-INF/web.xml");
context.setConfigurations(new Configuration[]{
            new AnnotationConfiguration(), new WebXmlConfiguration(),
            new WebInfConfiguration(), new TagLibConfiguration(),
            new PlusConfiguration(), new MetaInfConfiguration(),
            new FragmentConfiguration(), new EnvConfiguration()});

context.setContextPath("/");
context.setParentLoaderPriority(true);
context.setAttribute("org.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.ContainerIncludeJarPattern", ".*/classes/.*");
URL classes = Main.class
                .getProtectionDomain()
                .getCodeSource()
                .getLocation();

        
URL url = Main.class.getResource("/packageX/packageY/");
context.getMetaData().setWebInfClassesDirs(Arrays.asList(Resource.newResource(classes)));

//If i replace classes with url it can't find annotated filters or listeners.
//context.getMetaData().setWebInfClassesDirs(Arrays.asList(Resource.newResource(url)));

server.setHandler(context);
server.start();
server.join();
```

Above code is working fine but it scans for all packages in my fat jar which is time consuming. So I thought of narrowing down search space by giving package path for searching, but after that it can't find any annotated classes. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score -1):

The two attributes ...

- `org.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.ContainerIncludeJarPattern`
  for controlling what Container JARs are scanned.
- `org.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.WebInfIncludeJarPattern`
  for controlling what WebApp JARs are scanned.

.. only work at the JAR level.  Having a true uber-jar kinda makes both of those configurations have no meaning.

Have you considered just making your uber-jar a live-war instead? and separate the the container and webapp portions better?

See: https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-live-war

You could also do a pre-compute of the bytecode / annotation scannable components at build time and load the `WebAppContext` via the special `QuickStartWebApp` component instead, skipping the annotation scanning step entirely when embedded.

See: https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/quickstart-webapp.html

Comment: My solution works if I register all annotated filters and listeners in web.xml file. Is it a advisable solution in embedded jetty?